# SQL - Group By a Column, then Sort By the 'count' Results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

What I mean by Title is this: Say I have 100 row.  One column is `review_id`. I then want to `Group By` that `review_id`. Then I'd like to `count` each group of rows, and then `Sort By` it.

Sample results:  20 rows of review_id 132, 17 rows of `review_id` 434, 8 rows of `review_id` 22 - (this is sorting in descending)

How can I do this?   Here are the players involved:

A table called `vote` with `review_id` in a column.  it is being joined with a table called `reviews` with `review_id` as its unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(a.review_id) as total, a.review_id
FROM vote a
INNER JOIN reviews b
ON a.review_id = b.review_id
GROUP BY a.review_id
ORDER BY total ASC
```

Comment: Without the review_id in the select clause, this might only return one row, if it runs at all.

Comment: @DanBracuk not correct, it will return as many rows as there are combinations of review_id. It will just not show the column

Comment: I choose this answer as it did exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    count(vote.review_id) 
from vote, review
where
    vote.review_id = review.review_id
group by
    vote.review_id
```

Comment: I think you are missing a join to `review`.